# Using mod_rewrite and Apache as proxy for an R Shiny server

Tags: r, apache, mod-rewrite, shiny

I have a site run on a shiny server. The site itself poses no problems.

Then, there is this thing: I run shiny server locally only, connections can be made only from the localhost on port 9999. To permit access from outside, I use apache as a proxy. In the apache config file, I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect /shiny /shiny/
    ProxyPass /shiny/ http://127.0.0.1:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse /shiny http://127.0.0.1:9999/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works as intended (even though I am not entirely sure that the above is correct). Those who access http://myserver.name/shiny/ are getting the shiny server page, not Apache.

It turns out that the R Shiny server does not honor HEAD requests; they return 404 (apparently always). Why that is so is another matter; let us just assume for a moment that I can't do anything about that.

I would like the Apache to catch a HEAD request and rewrite it, such that the HEAD request would not fail, but return 200 OK. I tried to modify the above configuration as follows, but to no avail:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^HEAD
    RewriteRule ^/shiny(.*) /foo/
    Redirect /shiny /shiny/
    ProxyPass /shiny/ http://127.0.0.1:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse /shiny http://127.0.0.1:9999/
</VirtualHost>
```

(http://myserver.name/foo/ really exists). The above returns 404 whether I use any of the following:

```
curl -I http://myserver.name/shiny/
curl -I -L http://myserver.name/shiny/
```

My question: Why doesn't it work, but the following does:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^HEAD
    RewriteRule ^/shiny(.*) /foo/index.html
    Redirect /shiny /shiny/
    ProxyPass /shiny/ http://127.0.0.1:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse /shiny http://127.0.0.1:9999/
</VirtualHost>
```